# How I can check that an element in a grid of tiles is on my viewport fast?

Tags: c++, sdl, tile

I have a for loop that I use to draw a grid of tiles with sdl on a game. Since the grid is quite huge with more than 50k elements I want to optimize it.

So there is this function that use to check if I should draw a tile, so if it's outside of the screen I ignore it.

```
bool Camera::isInViewport(int &x, int &y, int &w, int &h) {
  int translatedX = x + offsetX;
  int translatedY = y + offsetY;

  if (translatedX + w >= 0 && translatedX <= 0 + sdl.windowWidth) {
    if (translatedY + h >= 0 && translatedY <= 0 + sdl.windowHeight) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

I checked this function it's eating 15% of the CPU alone when the grid is big. Will be possible to make this faster? I can't think of way that will make it eat less resources.

Comment: Do you store the tiles in a 2d array, or in some kind of 1d list (storing coordinates for each tile)?

Comment: Maybe subtract the x and y offsets (assuming they're fixed for the duration of the loop) from the width and height and store those values. That would eliminate two additions in the function call.

Comment: I use a 1D array

Comment: Are your tiles aligned to a grid? If so, switch to a 2D array and you won't need this function.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a lot that you can do with this funciton. Do not pass ints as references, it internally passes them as pointers, and it increases costs by dereferencing them. Merge conditions into one if statement and start from those that most probably will be evaluated into false to make early short-circuiting possible.

What I would do instead to solve this performance issue is to organize your tiles in 2D array where index and coordinates could be calculated from each other. In this case you just need to understand index boundaries of tiles covered by your viewport. Instead of checking result of this function on every cell you will be able to just tell left and right X index and top and down Y index. Then just draw them in two nested loops like that:

```
for (int y = topY; y <= bottomY; ++y)
    for (int x = leftX; x <= rightX; ++x)
        // do drawing with tile[y][x];
```

Another approach would be to cache the previous results. If camera is not moving and tiles are not moving - then result of this function is not going to change. Just storing flag that indicates you whether each tile is visible could work here (but not a good practice in big game), update them every time camera moves or recalculate tile if it moves (if it is possible in your app). Still recalculation of all visibility flags on camera movement will be expensive, so try to use first optimization and reduce the task by finding what tile range is affected by camera at all